# How do I find the language for a context free grammar?

Tags: context-free-grammar, context-free-language

I am having trouble determining the language from a given context free grammar. I've been given a hint that there are 2 parts to the language but cant figure either out.

```
G= ({S,A,B,C,D,E,Z},(0,1),R,S),

S→E|Z
E→A|C 
A→01B|0A|e
B→1B|10A 
C→10D|1C|e
D→01C|0D 
Z→0Z1|e
```

e is the empty string by the way. I have figured out that if it is Z the number of 0s and 1s are equal but cant figure out wh if it goes to E

Comment: Just make a few derivations of example terminal strings. This often gives you an idea of how the grammar operates and what it can generate. Then you probably recognize the patterns described by @Chris Dodd in  his answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kind of off topic, but you can pretty easily break down the grammar into subgrammars that you can analyze indepedently.

Firstly, the `E` rule only appears in one place on the RHS, so you can trivially substitute it and get rid of it by making the `S` rule `S→A|C|Z`.  Each of those non-terminals leads to an indepedent sublanguage (language A consisting of just the rules for `A` and `B`, language C with just `C` and `D`, and language Z with just `Z`.  Your language G is just the union of these three sublanguages.

Langauge A is trivially regular (due to all the non-terminals being at the end of the RHS of rules), and can be trivially transoformed into a 2 state E-NFA, which reduces to regexp (0|011*10)*

Language C similarly reduces to the regexp (1|100*01)*

Language Z is the only non-regular subpart and is the language { 0<sup>i</sup>1<sup>i</sup> | i ≥ 0 }

The union of these three is language G and doesn't really have any particularly good way of describing it other than the grammar.

Comment: How would A and C roughly translate to English?

Comment: A is begins and ends with 0 and does not contain any single isolated 1s (all 1s are in runs of at least 2).  C is the same with 1 and 0 reversed.